# Parent affect Child style in common selector using css

Tags: css

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="contact">
    <p>Testing p selector in child</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And these two css files:

default.css [Parent]

```
#content p {
color: #000000;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: helvetica;
text-align: left;
```

}

form.css [Child]

```
#contact p {
background-color: #F2F7FB;
font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;       
color: #3670A7;   
text-align: left;       
margin-right: 0px;       
padding-right: 0px;
```

}

Why the:

```
<p>Testing p selector in child</p>
```

is getting the parent's style and not the child's one?

Comment: Is your default.css loaded after form.css?

Comment: hahahaha, that's why!! @BoltClock'saUnicorn thanks!! post an answer to give u the credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to BoltClock'saUnicorn,

from comments: Is your default.css loaded after form.css?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the load order of your external .css files, but you can ensure that your style cascades get applied as you wish regardless of that order by using the "direct child" selector in your cascades.

Using `#contact > p`  and  `#content > p`  will indicate that when the `p` is a direct child of the container with the id it will use that style.

Comment: thanks for respond, there's already an answer for the question ;)